# WCF or ASP.NET 5 WEB API to create service for simple social network?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, social-networking

I am a beginner in .NET, and I write a simple social network. What would be better: WCF or ASP.NET 5 WEB API to create a service? And another problem: how to make two-way communication between the service and client (when user1 sends a message to user2, user2's message box has to change)? As far as I know, in WCF CallbackContract can be used, and how to do it in WEB API?

I will be very grateful for an answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend WCF's inbuilt capability if you want 2 way communication.

But from the scenario you have given you are talking about end users and not clients, today you want to send message to user 2, tommorrow it could be user3,user4 and so on.

So if you just want to collect some input from one of the end user through whatever means you prefer and broadcast to set of users you should user SignalR.

Comment: Thank You, I think SignalR is what I was looking for.